# How to navigate a JavaScript JSON object in JavaScript in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, navigation

Total newbie here. So, I'm trying to navigate some data from a JavaScript JSON, but I keep getting an error of, "navigation is not defined" whenever I click on my to a button. Can someone help me by showing some data (name, description, etc.) whenever I click on my touchableOpacity.

Here is my main code:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Text,
      Image,
      FlatList,
      ScrollView,
    } from "react-native";
    
    import Foods from "../const/Foods";
    import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
    
    export default class Recipes extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <SafeAreaView>
            <FlatList
              style={styles.mainList}
              data={Foods}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      navigation.navigate("Foods", item);
                    }}
                  >
                    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                      <View style={styles.itemList}>
                        <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.description}>{item.description}</Text>
                        <Image source={item.image} style={styles.image} />
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                );
              }}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        );
      }
    }
```

Here is my JavaScript JSON:

```
const foods = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Goto",
    description: "Ito ay parang lugaw din",
    ingredients: "Mixed Pizza",
    price: "8.30",
    image: require("../assets/recipes/goto.jpg"),
  },
];

export default foods;
```

Comment: What is `navigation.navigate("Foods", item)` supposed to do and why?  The error is pretty clear... `navigation` isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add navigation to your project, please check docs how to do it and how to use navigation properly: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started